# subtracting from timer actionscript 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2, countdowntimer, subtraction

I have this code for my timer

```
dt_timer.text = "02:00";
var dispSecs = 60;
var dispMins = 2;

var timerInterval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

function countDown()
{

    dispSecs--;

    if(dispSecs==59)
    {
        dispMins--;
    }

    if(dispSecs==0 && dispMins > 0)
    {
        dispSecs = 60;
    }

    if(dispSecs==0)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(200);
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
    }

    if(dispSecs == 60)
    {
        dt_timer.text = prependZero(dispMins) + ":" + prependZero(0);
    }
    else
    {
        dt_timer.text = prependZero(dispMins) + ":" +prependZero(dispSecs);
    }
}
function prependZero(num)
{
if (num < 10)
{
    num = "0" + num;
}
return (num);
}
```

**I have buttons that when clicked it will subtract 10 seconds from the timer. I was thingking of using this code in my button**

```
dispSecs - 10;
```

**is that right? Can anyone help me. please?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dispSecs += -10;
```

or

```
dispSecs = dispSecs - 10;
```

Comment: I think this may work too but it's been too long since I've messed with AS2, `dispSecs -= 10;`

Comment: Not a problem! If this helped don't forget to check it as the correct answer! This helps motivate members on the forum to continue offering free help and advice. Have a great day!